# CXF SOAP JAX-WS WSS4JInInterceptor change namespace and cause Unmarshalling error

Tags: soap, cxf, unmarshalling, saaj

I'm using WSS4JInInterceptor in my endpoint to validate the authorization.

I have that in my endpoint

Here it's my SOAP message

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header>
          <wsse:Security SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                 <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1">
                       <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
                       <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText"/>
                 </wsse:UsernameToken>
          </wsse:Security>
   </SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
          <newAsset xmlns="http://api.com.acme/">
                 <date xmlns="">2018-02-04T14:35:59Z</date>
                 <assetId xmlns="">1</assetId>
          </newAsset>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I trace the message into WSS4JInInterceptor and find out that the SOAP Message received was rewrited to : (the blank namespace where replaced)

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header>
          <wsse:Security SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                 <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1">
                       <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
                       <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText"/>
                 </wsse:UsernameToken>
          </wsse:Security>
   </SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
          <newAsset xmlns="http://api.com.acme/">
                 <date xmlns="http://api.com.acme/">2018-02-04T14:35:59Z</date>
                 <assetId xmlns="http://api.com.acme/">1</assetId>
          </newAsset>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

and that cause an unmarshalling error.

BUT

if I do a little change(Add a prefix) into my SOAP message to send this instead, WSS4JInInterceptor won't change the default namespace and the message will be accepted.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header>
          <wsse:Security SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                 <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1">
                       <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
                       <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText"/>
                 </wsse:UsernameToken>
          </wsse:Security>
   </SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
          <api:newAsset xmlns:api="http://api.com.acme/">
                 <date xmlns="">2018-02-04T14:35:59Z</date>
                 <assetId xmlns="">1</assetId>
          </api:newAsset>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

there is a way to avoid that ?   The first message was valid, so it should be accepted.  Do I have to put something in my xsd ?  I used unqualified.   I'm using CXF 3.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to CXF 3.0.3 and see if it still fails.   I think there were some issues around this that were recently fixed.  If it still fails, please log a bug with a testcase.

Comment: I don't see 3.0.3 on the main page.  http://cxf.apache.org/download.html   but it's in maven repository.  Now I have to test it for regression.  thanks again

Comment: I'll post another question, but just to keep a trace here too.  Now I can process the soap message received.  but when I have a xsd validation error (constraint) like number <0, I obtain a plain soapFault.  I'm using commonValidationFeature.  How can I obtain the validator error message ?