# How CXF SOAP convert XSD ContraintException to meaningful message?

Tags: soap, xsd, cxf, validation

I have a SOAP message that I'll validate using commonValidationFeature in CXF 3.0.3.  The validator works, but it's return a soap fault without meaningful error message.

I want to catch the ValidationException and convert it to a SOAP message with the error in a status error code.  I'll describe the output message later.

Here the soap fault returned :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
             <faultstring>Fault occurred while processing.</faultstring>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The validation error should be :

The field [xyz] is invalid, must be geater than 0.    (something like that)

Here it the field is the XSD

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="merchantId">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:long">
            <xs:minInclusive value="1" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

The java code generated
    @XmlElement(type = String.class)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Adapter2 .class)
    @DecimalMin("1")
    protected Long merchantId;

Here the validation used in my endpoint

```
<jaxws:features>
    <ref bean="commonValidationFeature" />
</jaxws:features>

<bean id="commonValidationFeature" class="org.apache.cxf.validation.BeanValidationFeature"/>
```

I tried to create my interceptor to catch the error, but when I do that, I get a schema validation error for unmarshalling. A message similar to my previous question : [CXF SOAP JAX-WS WSS4JInInterceptor change namespace and cause Unmarshalling error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27469863/cxf-soap-jax-ws-wss4jininterceptor-change-namespace-and-cause-unmarshalling-erro)

Here my code (a test code) for my interceptor

```
public class ExceptionInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {
    ConstraintViolationExceptionMapper mapper = new ConstraintViolationExceptionMapper();

    public ExceptionInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.PRE_LOGICAL);
    }

    public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
        Fault fault = (Fault) message.getContent(Exception.class);
        Throwable ex = fault.getCause();
        if (ex instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
            ConstraintViolationException e = (ConstraintViolationException) ex;

            Response response = mapper.toResponse(e);
            generateSoapFault(fault, e, response);
        } else {
            generateSoapFault(fault, null, null);
        }
    }

    private void generateSoapFault(Fault fault, Exception e, Response response) {
        fault.setFaultCode(createQName(response.getEntity().toString()));
    }

    private static QName createQName(String errorCode) {
        return new QName("qname.com", errorCode);
    }
}
```

What I would like to get as output, is something like that

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns6:newOutputResponse xmlns:ns6="http://demo.test" >
         <asset>
           ...
         </asset>

      <status>
         <type>ERROR</type>
         <description>[merchantId] is invalid, must be geater than 0.</description>
       </....
      </ns6...>
....
```

the tags  will be added only when there is a error.  How can I do that ?

Comment: Sebastien any luck finding the answer for your question?

Comment: Yes, I have something.  Thanks to make me remember to update this question.  I'll put the answer soon

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it.  We have to create a message response and populate this message with the ContrainsViolation error.  Here an example

```
public static StatusType createStatusType(Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> violations, Throwable ex, Fault fault){
    StatusType status;

    if(violations!=null) {
        status = new StatusType();
        status.setStatus(StatusFormat.ERROR);

        for (ConstraintViolation<?> violation : violations) {
            DetailType detailType = new DetailType();
            detailType.setCode(ErrorMessageConstant.PARAMETER_VALIDATION_ERR_CODE);
            detailType.setDescription(violation.getPropertyPath().toString() + " : " + violation.getMessage());

            status.getDetail().add(detailType);
        }
    } else if(ex instanceof javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException){
        status = new StatusType();
        status.setStatus(StatusFormat.ERROR);

        DetailType detailType = new DetailType();
        detailType.setCode(ErrorMessageConstant.PARAMETER_VALIDATION_ERR_CODE);
        detailType.setDescription(((UnmarshalException) ex).getLinkedException().getMessage());

        status.getDetail().add(detailType);
    } else {
        if(ex==null) {
            status = MessageHelper.buildStatusType(StatusFormat.ERROR, ErrorMessageConstant.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERR_CODE, fault.getMessage());
        } else {
            status = MessageHelper.buildStatusType(StatusFormat.ERROR, ErrorMessageConstant.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERR_CODE, ex.toString());
        }
    }

    return status;
}
```